# I want to divide date of a particular interval into 10 parts and query the count for each part in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, grouping

I have a table.

And it has two fields `id` and `datetime`.

What I need to do is, for any two given datetimes, I need to divide the time range into 10 equal intervals and give row count of each interval.

Please let me know whether this is possible without using any external support from languages like java or php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_col) / CAST((time2 - time1)/10) AS INT) + time1), count(id) from my_table where date_col >= time1 AND date_col <= time2 GROUP BY ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_col) / CAST((time2 - time1)/10) AS INT) + time1)
```

I haven't tested it. But something like this should work.

Comment: hey Chetan, Thanks. It is almost correct, just the group by clause and select column would by (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_col)-time1)/CAST((time2-time1)/10 as INT)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to divide date intervals is if you store them as longs (ie #of ticks from the "beginning of time"). As far as I know, there is no way to do it using MySQL's datetime.

How you decide to do it ultimately depends on your application. I would store them as longs and have whatever front end you are using handle to conversion to a more readable format.

What exactly do you mean by giving the row count of each interval? That part doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If i'll store them as long. Then, say my two intervals are 1318024876 and 1318030856. (100 minutes). So i need to divide them in 10 mins interval. and for each interval, i need the number of rows belonging to that interval.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you want this:

SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE datetime > 'time1' AND datetime < 'time1' + interval;

Comment: But i'll have to run it for each interval. I found the answer. the above answer is the write one. Thanks anyways for the help.